# Most likely estimate of maximum of discrete uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

For my homework I have to answer the following question:

A company has manufactured certain objects and has printed a serial number
on each manufactured object. The serial numbers start at 1 and end at N, where
N is the number of objects that have been manufactured. One of these objects
is selected at random, and the serial number of that object is 888. What is the
method of moments estimate of N? What is the mle of N?

The method of moments estimate I could do as $E[x] = \frac{N+1}{2} = \mu_1 = \frac{888}{1}$.
However im stuck at using maximum likelihood as I don't know how to use the formula $\prod\limits_{i = 0}^{n} f(X_i|\sigma)$ here. Would $\sigma$ be N? In that case what even is for example $P(N=1)$ or $P(N=888)$??

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: $P(X|N) = 1/ N$ as long as $X \leq N$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that helped me find the answer

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the green checkmark to the side of its vote count. This is a more helpful way of indicating that the question has been answered.

Comment: This is known as the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) and is a classic example of the bias of a maximum likelihood estimator

Comment: @AaronMontgomery done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X|N) = 1/ N$ as long as $X \leq N$ and is 0 otherwise.  So the likelihood function for $N$ is equal to 0 for $N < 888$ and is $ =1/N$ for $N \geq 888$.  This function is maximized for $N = 888$.